# Why do BBC News use so many 'quotes' in headlines

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have noticed a that the BBC News website seems to use quotes in their headlines in places where I can see no reason to do so. Take the following story:

[Julius Malema: South Africa issues 'arrest warrant'](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-19680419)

Which on the front page, even more noticably is headed

> S Africa issues Malema 'warrant'

Why does the word "warrant" warrant quotes? Surely there's no legal or attributional 'reason' to do so? Surely these are just plain facts? If you're going to put quotes around "warrant" you might as well put quotes around "issues" too.

I find this very 'annoying' because to me it reads like they're casting doubt on the news they're 'reporting'.

(Arrgh, it's 'catching')

EDIT: Of course I know the reason for the use of quotes in newspaper stories. I am asking why the BBC in particular uses them so much. In an attempt to reopen this question, I submit another example:

[Turkey trial: Three army generals jailed for 'coup plot'](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-19670530)

In this story, the three generals in question have been sentenced. So why the quotes?

[Apple promises maps app will 'improve'](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-19672981)

In this story, sure "improve" is a quote from an Apple source, but I don't understand why it should be put in quotes. Surely the "Apple promises..." part makes this clear?

Comment: In this particular instance it seems to be because Mr. Malema's lawyer *claims* a warrant has been issued, but "The authorities have refused to comment on reports about the arrest warrant."

Comment: I think this is non-constructive "peeving". OP is obviously familiar with such use of quote marks, since he does it himself. In this specific case it seems likely BBC aren't completely convinced  an *actual* arrest warrant has in fact been issued (the story goes on to say the relevant authorities refuse to comment).

Comment: @StoneyB: [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL), but if I were, I'd have advised you to either use quote marks yourself, or refer to it as a *so-called arrest warrant* :)

Comment: It's not just in this case. I can add other examples if necessary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  What else is it you think I should have enclosed in quotes? I thought of "claims", but this is *my* word, not from the story.

Comment: @Groky: Other examples by the BBC? Other examples by other publishing organisations? You *know* the general significance of slapping quote marks around *someone else's description*, or indeed around *any term which the writer is unable/unwilling to fully endorse*. What good would more examples do?

Comment: @StoneyB: It was only in fun, obviously - I meant you should have considered putting "quote marks within quote marks" when quoting that line from the BBC's webpage. But even though IANAL, I guess you'll be safe on account of the outer quote marks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Like Prince Philip, I always enjoy a good joke once it's pointed out to me.

Comment: On another website, the 'partial single quote-mark quote' 'used especially by the BBC' was suggested to be a 'way of reporting hearsay - of varying degrees of accuracy' and 'way of communicating near- (or not-so-near-) quotes' 'without having to bother doing the research they should to verify or otherwise' and 'without exposing themselves to possible legal action for libel'.